# react-id-swiper nested interactive components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, swiper.js

I am trying to create slider on ecommerce site. I want to add some card components inside slider.
Thous components are interactive with ability to add a product to shopping cart.
But since swiper cloning its slides - part of slides is not working as i want them to.

I created [example](https://codepen.io/veezex/pen/mddMJBz) with simple nested component.

```
const Counter = props => {
  const [val, setVal] = React.useState(0);

  return <div>
    <button onClick={e => setVal(val + 1)}>+</button>
    <span>{val}</span>
    <button onClick={e => setVal(val - 1)}>-</button>
  </div>
}

const Swiper = ReactIdSwiper.default;

const params = {
  loop: true,
  slidesPerView: 3,
  spaceBetween: 50
}

ReactDOM.render(<Swiper {... params}>
      {[1,2].map(slide => <div key={slide} class="swiper-slide">Slide {slide} <Counter/></div>)}
    </Swiper>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

In this example 1st and 2nd counters are working, but 3rd (duplicate of 1st) is just a static piece of html.

Is it possible create slider with nested components using [swiper](https://swiperjs.com) (it is already used on the site)? If not, are there sliders for the job?